# How to specify the character set for a Sybase JDBC connection using jTDS?

Tags: java, jdbc, character-encoding, sybase, jtds

I am using jTDS to connect to a Sybase database, and non-ASCII character data is broken. This happens both in my own app and in SQuirreLSQL.

Where can I specify the character set to be used for the connection? And can I find out what that character set should be somewhere in the data dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the charset property

> charset (default - the character set the server was installed with)
>       Very important setting, determines the byte value to character mapping for CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT values. Applies for characters from the
>   extended set (codes 128-255). For NCHAR/NVARCHAR/NTEXT values doesn't
>   have any effect since these are stored using Unicode.

Simply append `;<property>=<value>` to your JDBC URL.

See [the FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)

Comment: Now I am getting an `SQLWarning ErrorCode:   2409 SQLState: S1000 --- Cannot find the requested character set in Syscharsets:  name = 'eucgb'`. But the Chinese characters display fine now (which they did not without the charset option, even though it is presumably wrong now). Weird...